# React Admin is not showing Search Bar

Tags: reactjs, filter, react-admin

I am using react-admin v2.9.6 with firebase.
But it is not showing the search bar even if I added it in my code.
Seriously there is a bug which I can see in my console logs.

[image: My console screenshot]

Here is my code and anyone who can help me contact me if you like.

```
const SearchFilter = props => (
  <Filter {...props}>
    <TextField label="Search" source="name" alwaysOn />
  </Filter>
)

export const SearchList = props => (
  <List {...props} filters={<SearchFilter />}>
    <Datagrid>
      <TextField source="name" />
      <TextField source="avgRating" />
      <TextField source="numReviews" />
      <EditButton label="" />
      <DeleteButton label="" redirect={false} />
    </Datagrid>
  </List>
)
```

[image: No Filter now]

I love react.js but react-admin is the first time.
Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

In your SearchFilter component, try using `<TextInput />` instead of `<TextField />`

Like this:

```
const SearchFilter = props => (
  <Filter {...props}>
    <TextInput label="Search" source="name" alwaysOn />
  </Filter>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case this issue/problem is still active for you. Doctor Agon is right, use TextInput instead of TextField as a Field only can read already defined value which comes from TextInput.